# Intermittent connection issues with atheros ar9285

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have an asus K50IJ which has an atheros ar9285 wifi chip. It has decided to start to randomly drop internet. Although the card doesn't seem to notice it has. It will show full signal instead of say 3 bars. I tried to look at the atheros site for the latest driver but they don't even offer driver downloads. I then checked the asus site and it doesn't even list that card in the downloads for this laptop. I run Windows 7 64bit. It will drop either every minute or once a day while I am doing intensive bandwidth usage and when I am just idling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many OEM's are having problems with their versions of the Atheros drivers, go to this site and get an updated driver, it seems to solve many Atheros complaints.

http://www.atheros.cz/

Comment: Saw that site, but it had a .cz tld and looked sketchy. But I will check it out

Comment: I see it linked to in many forums as the Atheros solution, I know what you mean though.

Comment: And when I try to install it windows says my driver is up to date :(

Comment: Another suggestion, change the wireless radio channel in your router, keep changing it until you find a stable channel.

Comment: I have gone through all the channels. Happens in both Windows and Linux.